# Removing an argument from arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, javascript-objects

I wanted to have an optional `boolean` parameter to a function call:

```
function test() {
  if (typeof(arguments[0]) === 'boolean') {
    // do some stuff
  }
  // rest of function
}
```

I want the rest of the function to only see the `arguments` array **without** the optional `boolean` parameter. First thing I realized is the `arguments` array isn't an array! It seems to be a standard `Object` with properties of 0, 1, 2, etc. So I couldn't do:

```
function test() {
  if (typeof(arguments[0]) === 'boolean') {
    var optionalParameter = arguments.shift();
```

I get an error that `shift()` doesn't exist. So is there an easy way to remove an argument from the beginning of an `arguments` object?

Comment: Just a guess: `delete arguments[0]`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`arguments` is not an array, it is an array like object. You can call the array function in `arguments` by accessing the [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) and then invoke it by passing the `argument` as its execution context using [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Try

```
var optionalParameter = Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
```

Demo

```js
function test() {
    var optionalParameter;
    if (typeof (arguments[0]) === 'boolean') {
        optionalParameter = Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
    }
    console.log(optionalParameter, arguments)
}
test(1, 2, 3);
test(false, 1, 2, 3);
```

another version I've seen in some places is

```
var optionalParameter = [].shift.apply(arguments);
```

Demo

```js
function test() {
    var optionalParameter;
    if (typeof (arguments[0]) === 'boolean') {
        optionalParameter = [].shift.apply(arguments);
    }
    console.log(optionalParameter, arguments)
}
test(1, 2, 3);
test(false, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Note that this will affect any named arguments as well, and has a particularly interesting effect on the last argument provided when it's accessed as a named argument. If you have `function foo(a, b, c)` and you call `foo(1, 2, 3)` and do the shift above, both `b` and `c` will end up being `3`. This may be what you want. Or not.

Comment: Surprised this works! so `shift` not only returns back the first element, but converts the `Object` passed in to an `array` and then back into an `Object` with the first element removed? Exactly what I was looking for, but surprising...

Comment: @at that's not actually what it does. The "shift" code runs and "pretends" that the object is really an array; it performs no conversion.  It's for that reason that this trick has the effect noded by Mr. Crowder. If you need to do this sort of thing, you should probably just convert `arguments` to an array and work from there.

Comment: If you want to leave `arguments` untouched and create a new array use slice: `var newArguments = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);`

Comment: What's important to understand is that in Javascript, functions are themselves objects and so can have a life on their own. You can take them from one object and put them onto another. Combine this with the fact that all array functions, by contract, only depend on the object having a `length` property and you can see why this solution works.

Answer (score 2):

As Arun pointed out `arguments` is not an array

You will have to convert in into an array

`var optionalParameter = [].shift.apply(arguments);`

Comment: Arun's original answer did not have the alternative solution. It was added later

Answer (score 1):

It's not fancy but the best solution to remove the first argument without side effect (without ending with an additional argument as would do `shift`) would probably be

```
  for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) arguments[i]=arguments[i+1];
```

Example :

```
function f(a, b, c, d) {
  for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) arguments[i]=arguments[i+1];
  console.log(a,b,c,d); 
}
f(1,2,3,4); // logs 2,3,4,undefined
```

Comment: After your code runs, `arguments.length === 4`. I think you should finish the job by setting it to `arguments.length-1` after the for loop.