# How to unshift or add to the beginning of arguments object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, javascript-objects, argument-passing

I've just learned the [convention for popping off the first element of the `arguments` array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903841/removing-an-argument-from-arguments-in-javascript) (which I also learned is actually an `Object`). Now I need to do the opposite. I need to use an `unshift` operation to add a value to the beginning of the `arguments` array (or `Object` acting like an array). Is this possible? I tried:

```
Array.prototype.unshift.apply('hello', arguments);
```

That had no effect on `arguments` whatsoever.

Comment: You cannot modify the `arguments` collection. You can modify the argument values, but not the length of the collection etc.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, you can modify its length.

Comment: @BlueSkies yes sorry; what I meant was that you can't mess with it like an array. Changing the length of an array affects array elements after the new length by making them `undefined`, but updating the length of the `arguments` object won't do that. I should have worded my comment more clearly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. use `.call()` instead of `.apply()` to invoke `unshift()`
2. set `arguments` as the `this` value of `unshift()`
3. set `'hello'` as the argument to `unshift()`

---

```
Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, 'hello');
```

---

As @lonesomeday pointed out, you can use `.apply()` instead of `.call()`, but you need to pass an array-like argument as the second argument. So in your case, you'd need to wrap `'hello'` in an Array.

Comment: You could also do `apply(arguments, ['hello'])`.

Comment: This gives me a strange result in Chrome: `['hello', 'argument1', undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`