# How to add another entry at the beginning of this JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

I get this test data from my server, as JSON:

```
{
    "0": {
        "campaign_id": "1",
        "title": "Nike Air 2015 campaign",
        "description": null,
        "path_to_logo": null,
        "start_time": "09/11/2015 22:42:08",
        "end_time": "09/03/2016 22:42:08",
        "paused": "0",
        "destinations": {
            "0": {
                "destination_id": "1",
                "url": "www.nike.com/nike_air",
                "description": "Nike air destination",
                "connections": {
                    "0": {
                        "connection_id": "3",
                        "tag_id": "0",
                        "country": "Scotland",
                        "county": "Yorkshire",
                        "town": "East Ham",
                        "post_code": "SE1 1AA",
                        "custom": "bus stop",
                        "description": "Connection number 3"
                    }
                }
            },
            "1": {
                "destination_id": "2",
                "url": "www.nike.com/nike_air/sub_campaign",
                "description": "Nike air - free laces promotion destination",
                "connections": {
                    "0": {
                        "connection_id": "2",
                        "tag_id": "0",
                        "country": "Engerland",
                        "county": "Devon",
                        "town": "East Ham",
                        "post_code": "SE1 1AA",
                        "custom": "bus stop",
                        "description": "Connection number 2"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "connection_id": "4",
                        "tag_id": "0",
                        "country": "Engerland",
                        "county": "Yorkshire",
                        "town": "Felixswtowe",
                        "post_code": "RB3 9YR",
                        "custom": "police staticon",
                        "description": "Connection number 4"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "connection_id": "6",
                        "tag_id": "0",
                        "country": "Scotland",
                        "county": "Essex",
                        "town": "York",
                        "post_code": "JD8 4LF",
                        "custom": "somewhere else",
                        "description": "Connection number 6"
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "connection_id": "9",
                        "tag_id": "0",
                        "country": "Scotland",
                        "county": "Cork",
                        "town": "York",
                        "post_code": "JD8 4LF",
                        "custom": "in the ladies' loo",
                        "description": "Connection number 9"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "campaign_id": "2",
        "title": "Nike football boots campaign",
        "description": null,
        "path_to_logo": null,
        "start_time": "09/12/2015 22:42:08",
        "end_time": "09/01/2016 22:42:08",
        "paused": "0",
        "destinations": {
            "0": {
                "destination_id": "3",
                "url": "www.nike.com/nike_football_boots/",
                "description": "Nike footie boots destination",
                "connections": {}
            },
            "1": {
                "destination_id": "4",
                "url": "www.nike.com/nike_football_boots/sub_campaign",
                "description": "Buy left boot, get right boot free destination",
                "connections": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "campaign_id": "3",
        "title": "Nike general promotion campaign",
        "description": null,
        "path_to_logo": null,
        "start_time": "09/12/2013 22:42:08",
        "end_time": "09/08/2016 22:42:08",
        "paused": "0",
        "destinations": {
            "0": {
                "destination_id": "5",
                "url": "www.nike.com/general_promotion",
                "description": "Nike general promotion destination",
                "connections": {}
            },
            "1": {
                "destination_id": "6",
                "url": "www.nike.com/general_promotion/discount_coupon",
                "description": "20% off coupon destination",
                "connections": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add a new "campaign" **at the front**.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913641/how-to-unshift-or-add-to-the-beginning-of-arguments-object-in-javascript), I try

```
    var date = new Date();  
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var blankCampaignData = {'title': '', 'description': '', 'path_to_logo': '',   
                             'start_time': date, 'end_time' : date, 'paused': false};

   Array.prototype.unshift.call($scope.campaignData, blankCampaignData);
```

But, after that I have a single object, containing `blankCampaignData`.

How do I achieve what I wanted to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773813/adding-something-to-the-top-of-a-json-object will help

Comment: maybe you consider to use an array insttead of an object.

Comment: You cannot use unshift with Objects.
This question is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically